# "Untick" vs. "uncheck": which is more common in Canadian English?

Tags: word-usage, verbs, differences, canadian-english

I'd be grateful if any Canadian speakers can tell me: in the context of an option in a computer dialog box/menu, which of the words "untick" vs "uncheck" is most commonly used (or are they used interchangeably)?

Comment: I'm in Australia and we would never say uncheck, only untick. You tick boxes here, not check them.

Comment: "tick" to mean "check mark" has British origins. I can see why Australians would use it over check.

Comment: Just for context, the reason I'm here is Android Studio doesn't recognize both Untick and Uncheck.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

*Uncheck* is far more common. Anecdotally, I have rarely seen the word *untick* while I fairly regularly hear and use the word *uncheck*.

But, to demonstrate it better, do a [google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=untick&cr=countryCA) for *untick* with Canadian location. It lists 16,200 results. By contrast, [searching for *uncheck*](http://www.google.com/search?q=uncheck&cr=countryCA) with Canadian location returns 695,000 results.

Comment: Clever use of Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Both would be understood. I would say uncheck is more common. Don't think I've ever heard "untick" used.

Answer (score 1):

I am not Canadian, but I always use "untick" rather than "uncheck". It can be a bit annoying because most online dictionaries don't recognise it, despite it being in common use online.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. Please note that this is not a discussion forum, but a Q&A site; while personal anecdotes are welcome, they should be relevant to answering the question at hand. For example, do you live in, or are you from Canada? Are there other examples, say from Canadian media or government websites, that would illustrate the usage? I encourage you to take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.