# What can a user do with a checkbox?

Tags: word-choice, verbs

When user is presented with a checkbox on a webpage. What can he/she do with it in order to place a little birdy inside it?

- check (Please, check the checkbox...)
- tick (Please, tick the checkbox...)
- mark (Please, mark the checkbox...)

Comment: Uh, flip the bird?

Comment: You answered your own question. All three can be used. My favorite is *tick the checkbox*.

Comment: Related: [Untick/Uncheck](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/19183/use-of-untick-uncheck-in-canadian-english)

Comment: Of course, whoever reviews the checkboxes later will have to check for ticks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could consider *select* too.

> Please select the checkbox.

The meaning of *checkbox* reported by the NOAD is the following one:

> a small box on a computer screen that, when selected by the user, is filled with an X to show that the feature described alongside it has been enabled.

Comment: Also "click", although "select" is more correct.

Comment: If adhering to [Microsoft style guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa511452.aspx) (documentation section at the bottom here) _select_ and its opposite _clear_ are the things you do with a check box (two words, for _check box_, in this style). [Here's another example](http://www.clickstart.net/?page_id=29) from a review of the Microsoft Manual of Style. Some authors and products follow these styles just to be consistent with what is familiar.

Comment: "Select" is ambiguous to me: it could also mean "give it focus" or "highlight it by holding the left mouse button and dragging".

Comment: Our internal style guide calls for "select" and "clear" as well.

Answer (score 0):

Consider "**activate**", which is described by [oxforddictionaries.com](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/activate) as

> Make (something) active or operative

The opposite operation would of course be to "deactivate" the checkbox.